# DataGrip Postgres SSL error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException

Tags: postgresql, ssl, datagrip

DataGrip won't connect to my Postgres instance, but I can connect fine via `psql` on the terminal:

```
psql -h dbhost.com reps username
>Password for user... (connects)
```

However, IntelliJ DataGrip throws:

```
Connection to username@dbhost.com failed.
SSL error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The connection string it uses is `jdbc:postgresql://dbhost.com:5432/dbname`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try disabling the SSL checkbox in the SSH/SSL tab in your database's property window.

Then append `?sslmode=require` to the URL in the General tab so that it reads something like:
 `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/reps?sslmode=require`

Comment: This also helped me connect to Postgres via PhpStorm

Comment: Works for PyCharm as well

Comment: does not work for me, I use ssl cert ca file and disabling ssl is not a solution

Comment: sslMode or useSSL can be set in the advanced settings for the connection.

Comment: Under "Advanced" in the connection property window I had to set "trustServerCertificate" to true

Answer (score 4):

Change `sslmode` to `disable` in `Advanced` tab in you database's `property` window

Comment: This worked for me. I had the connection to my AWS RDS instance. Nothing changed( as far as I know), out of blue it shows 08006 SSL connection Error. I didn't have to disable SSL and neither co-workers working right next to me(they still have the connection without disabling SSL). Wonder why..

Comment: Notably, for me setting "encrypt" to false in the advanced tab was required (sslmode was already set to disable)